# Jquery checkboxes within containing table selector question

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, css-selectors

**My current code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkAll(checked) {
        $("input[type='checkbox']:not([disabled='disabled'])").attr('checked', checked);
    }
</script>
<input type="checkbox" id="cbxSelectAll" onclick="checkAll(this.checked);" />
```

**The short version:**

How do I modify the function call and method above to check all checkboxes inside a table containing the checxbox form element.

**The long version:**

I am creating a WebUserControl containing a grid view in asp.net that is going to have a delete option. I would like the delete to be a series of checkboxes with one a box in the header to select all of them. What this amounts to for non ASP.NET people is a table with a header row that has a checkbox and every row also has a checxbox.

I have used the above code to check all boxes on the entire page. That won't work here though because I want to have multiple of these on the page at once each working independently. I know I could use a selector to select all the boxes if I ID'd the table but that would require some coding to name the table uniquely and then put that name in the script block.

Really what I would like is to modify the script above to check all checkboxes in the containing table of the "select all" box. The table containing the checkbox could be nested within others but I don't see any being nested within it, or if there are and the nested table also contains checxboxes I don't care if they also get selected.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't mix your HTML and your Javascript.  Use event handler binding instead.

Second, use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to get the nearest ancestor element of a particular type:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cbxSelectAll').click(function() {
        $(this)
            .closest('table') // get the parent table element
            .find("input:checkbox:enabled") // find children that match the selector
            .attr('checked', this.checked); // set their checked value
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you want to change the .closest to find the parent table element.  Something like .closest('table').

Comment: `:checkbox:enabled` is much better as well.

Comment: I like this method but to use it for multiple "select all boxes" on the same page could I alter the first selector to be "input:checxbox.selectAll" instead of "#cbxSelectAll"?

Answer (score 2):

Change your inline attribute to this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cbxSelectAll" onclick="checkAll.call(this);" />
```

And your `checkAll()` to this:

```
function checkAll() {
    $(this).closest('table').find("input:checkbox:enabled").attr('checked', this.checked);
}
```

Using `.call()`, it is called from the context of the element clicked.

Then the jQuery gets the [`closest()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) `<table>` and finds the inputs using the [`checkbox-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) and the [`enabled-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/) .

Then when using the [`attr()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method, you can use `this.checked` to set the checkboxes to the current state of the one checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the table containing the select all using `.closest`

```
function checkAll(checked) {
    var $table = $(this).closest('table');
    $table.find("input[type='checkbox']:not([disabled='disabled'])")
          .attr('checked', checked);
}
```

If there might be several nested tables it's often easiest to specify the one you want with a class, e.g. `$(this).closest('table.tableOfCheckboxes');` where you add class tableOfCheckboxes to the table you want to find.